# PhpStorm: Highlight variables with no known type?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

PhpStorm does a great job of reading type hints and inferring types of variables from their usage. But it gives no warning when it cannot determine a reasonable type for a variable. The obvious downside is if you use a variable in a way thats illegal when it doesn't know the type it will never raise a warning.

Is it possible to raise a warning or highlight a variable if it cannot determine the type of it? The fix would be add an explicit type hint or missing return annotations.

Comment: *"Is it possible to raise a warning or highlight a variable if it cannot determine the type of it?"* No. I mean -- there is no such out-of-the-box functionality (it's rather useless as for me) ... but you should be able to make a custom plugin for such stuff (using Java/Kotlin though) -- compared to other plugins that work with inspections this one should be rather simple. You may also ask devs/custom plugin author to add such functionality (e.g. "Php Inspections (EA Extended)" plugin)